# iOS swift push notification

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am making an app to receive notification. I have followed few tutorials and made a sample app.I have also configured it to show alert, badge and sound when notification is received.

I also completed all firebase configurations.Then I launched an iphone7 simulator.

Now I am trying to send a message using firebase. The message is sent from firebase. I also see the message received in the debug window of Xcode but the message doesn't show as an alert on the simulator at all.

I read somewhere that push notification doesn't work for simulator, so I attached an iPhone device having IOS 9.0 built and ran.

Now I do not see message even in the debug window. 
Please help me what should I do to test push notification.

Here is the [link](http://sandbox.rkshahclinic.org/apple/AppDelegate.swift) to my code:
http://sandbox.rkshahclinic.org/apple/AppDelegate.swift

Comment: if your appp is foreground, it does not show,

Comment: What is the output/ Result in your firebase console?

Comment: firebase says 'completed'. As I said when I run the same program in simulator the Xcode debug window shows that the message is received but the same debug window and same program shows nothing when I run on a real device.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a notification if your app is foreground.

For iOS 10 you need integrate willPresentNotification method for show notification banner in foreground.

If app in foreground mode(active)

```
- (void)userNotificationCenter:(UNUserNotificationCenter* )center willPresentNotification:(UNNotification* )notification withCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UNNotificationPresentationOptions options))completionHandler {
    NSLog( @“Handle push notification in foreground" ); 
    //For notification Banner - when app in foreground

    completionHandler(UNNotificationPresentationOptionAlert);

    // Print Notification info
    NSLog(@"info %@",notification.request.content.userInfo);
}
```

Comment: I am receiving nothing - whether foreground or background

Comment: func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo

        if let messageID = userInfo[gcmMessageIDKey] {
            print("Message ID: \(messageID)")
        }
     
        print(userInfo)

        completionHandler([.alert,.sound,.badge])
    }

Comment: should I load app in App Store and then distribute for testing in order to test this feature. Does it not work by directly connecting a phone to Xcode and executing run command. Please advice.

Comment: In question is written that iOS version is 9.0, so to receive that notification you need method `application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification data: [AnyHashable : Any])`